# Convert XML with multiple lists of objects into POJO's using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, pojo

I've been working to get a XML file with a list of Customers to convert to usable POJO's in JAVA using JAXB. After following [This Tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/jaxb-exmaple-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-or-set-of-objects) I am getting a null pointer exception when trying to load the list of Customers. I have been printing out what methods get reached, and it seems to not ever call the `setCustomers(...) {...}` function. Here is the format of the XML:

```
<Customers>
    <Customer>
      <Age>86</Age>
      <CustomerId>101</CustomerId>
      <Email>R_Heimbach@gmail.net</Email>
      <Name>Robert Heimbach</Name>
      <Orders>
        <Order>
          <CustomerId>101</CustomerId>
          <Lines>
            <OrderLine>
              <OrderLineId>299</OrderLineId>
              <Price>12</Price>
              <ProductId>1785</ProductId>
              <Qty>1</Qty>
              <Total>12</Total>
            </OrderLine>
          </Lines>
          <OrderId>148</OrderId>
          <Total>12</Total>
        </Order>
        <Order>
          <CustomerId>101</CustomerId>
          <Lines>
            <OrderLine>
              <OrderLineId>300</OrderLineId>
              <Price>51</Price>
              <ProductId>8107</ProductId>
              <Qty>2</Qty>
              <Total>102</Total>
            </OrderLine>
          </Lines>
          <OrderId>149</OrderId>
          <Total>102</Total>
        </Order>
      </Orders>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
      <Age>63</Age>
      <CustomerId>102</CustomerId>
      <Email>B_Smith@gmail.net</Email>
      <Name>Bob Smith</Name>
      <Orders>
        <Order>
          <CustomerId>102</CustomerId>
          <Lines>
            <OrderLine>
              <OrderLineId>300</OrderLineId>
              <Price>12</Price>
              <ProductId>1785</ProductId>
              <Qty>1</Qty>
              <Total>12</Total>
            </OrderLine>
          </Lines>
          <OrderId>149</OrderId>
          <Total>12</Total>
        </Order>
        <Order>
          <CustomerId>102</CustomerId>
          <Lines>
            <OrderLine>
              <OrderLineId>301</OrderLineId>
              <Price>51</Price>
              <ProductId>8107</ProductId>
              <Qty>2</Qty>
              <Total>102</Total>
            </OrderLine>
          </Lines>
          <OrderId>149</OrderId>
          <Total>102</Total>
        </Order>
      </Orders>
    </Customer>
```

My Customers.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customers")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customers {

    @XmlElement(name = "Customer")
    private List<Customer> customers = null;

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    public void setCustomers(List<Customer> customers) {
        for(Customer customer : customers) {
            System.out.println(customer.getName());
        }
        this.customers = customers;
    }
    
}
```

My Customer.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {
    
    @XmlElement(name = "CustomerId")
    private int customerId;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Age")
    private int age;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Email")
    private String email;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Orders")
    private List<Order> orders = null;

    
    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
    
}
```

My Order.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Order")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Order {

    @XmlElement(name = "OrderId")
    private int orderId;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "CustomerId")
    private int customerId;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Total")
    private int total;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Lines")
    private List<OrderLine> lines = null;

    public int getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public List<OrderLine> getLines() {
        return lines;
    }

    public void setLines(List<OrderLine> lines) {
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

}
```

My OrderLine.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "OrderLine")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OrderLine {

    @XmlElement(name = "OrderLineId")
    private int orderLineId;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Price")
    private int price;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "ProductId")
    private int productId;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Qty")
    private int qty;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Total")
    private int total;


    public int getOrderLineId() {
        return orderLineId;
    }

    public void setOrderLineId(int orderLineId) {
        this.orderLineId = orderLineId;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
    
}
```

the main funtion:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            File file = new File("customers.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customers.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            
            Customers customers = (Customers) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

            System.out.println(customers.getCustomers().size());

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have a feeling my annotations are a bit mixed up. What would be causing the `System.out.println(customers.getCustomers().size());` to result in an NullPointerException when it runs? It seems to parse it all but doesn't assign anything in the POJO's.